# JavaFX ObjectInputStream Color stays null

Tags: javafx, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I write `<Edge>` objects to a file like this

```
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream("Object" + level + ".txt"));

    edgeList = koch.getEdgeList();
    for (Edge e : edgeList) {
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(e);
    }
```

Edges contains Colors:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;


public class Edge implements Serializable {

    public double X1, Y1, X2, Y2;
    transient public Color color;

    public Edge(double X1, double Y1, double X2, double Y2, Color color) {
        this.X1 = X1;
        this.Y1 = Y1;
        this.X2 = X2;
        this.Y2 = Y2;
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

I'm using javaFX and can't change this.
I made the Color transient because it would cause trouble with the Serializable if I did not do this.

Now I read the objectfile like this:

```
FileInputStream streamIn = new FileInputStream("Object" + level + ".txt");
    ObjectInputStream objectinputstream = new ObjectInputStream(streamIn);
    int teller = 0;
    try {
        for (teller = 0; teller < i; teller++) {
            Edge edge = (Edge) objectinputstream.readObject();
            EdgeList.add(edge);
        }
    } catch (OptionalDataException e) {
        if (!e.eof) {
            throw e;
        }
    } finally {

        objectinputstream.close();

    }
```

The problem I have now is that when I read the Edge object from the file, the coordinates (X1, Y1, X2, Y2) read fine. But the color is NULL, this does not cause an error, but it will simply not show a color to a drawn line. So I do not have any error code. I have to manually set a Color but i should get a color from the objectfile.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom serialized form for your `Edge` class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream ;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream ;
import java.io.IOException ;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;


public class Edge implements Serializable {

    public double X1, Y1, X2, Y2;
    transient public Color color;

    public Edge(double X1, double Y1, double X2, double Y2, Color color) {
        this.X1 = X1;
        this.Y1 = Y1;
        this.X2 = X2;
        this.Y2 = Y2;
        this.color = color;
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream s) throws IOException {
        s.defaultWriteObject();
        s.writeDouble(color.getRed());
        s.writeDouble(color.getGreen());
        s.writeDouble(color.getBlue());
        s.writeDouble(color.getOpacity());
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream s) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        s.defaultReadObject();
        double red = s.readDouble();
        double green = s.readDouble();
        double blue = s.readDouble();
        double opacity = s.readDouble();
        color = Color.color(red, green, blue, opacity);
    }
}
```

This will automatically serialize the color *data* (the rgba values) for you, and recreate the color object from those data on deserialization.

I created a [complete demo](https://gist.github.com/james-d/a7202039b00170256293) of this, which also serializes JavaFX properties using the same technique, but is a little too long to post directly here.